# Is it possible to convert java primitive and reference object types to a byte array as same as user-defined objects?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, primitive-types

I want to write a class to serialize all of the objects in my code (primitive, reference and user-defined). For the user-defined objects I have written the following code:

```
static void serialize(Object object, OutputStream outputStream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput objectOutput = null;
    try {
        objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        objectOutput.writeObject(object);
        objectOutput.flush();
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        outputStream.write(bytes);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to reuse the same method for primitive and reference object types and what should I change in the method?

Comment: `string` doesn't exists. You probably meant `String` which is not a primitive

Comment: enums aren't primitive types either. you may want to start with reading up on what exactly primitive types are

Comment: What now? Primitive types such as double? Or reference types, such as String, Double, enum? In other words, it is really unclear what you are asking or trying to achieve.

Comment: and regarding your question's title - can you tell me how would you convert a `boolean` `true` to a byte array `byte[]`...?

Comment: @Lino  yes I meant String and I thought it is primitive, however, I would like one way to convert objects byte array regardless their type declaration.

Comment: I edited my post I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the fact that you don't really do anything with the `ID` type you can just simplify it to `Object`. Also if you happen to use Java7 you can make use of the `try-with-resources` statement. The `FileNotFoundException` also seems to not be used. So the final version of your `serialize` method would look like:

```
static void serialize(Object o, OutputStream outputStream){
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)){
        objectOutput.writeObject(o);
        objectOutput.flush();
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        outputStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

That way you can call this method with what ever object you desire to serialize:

```
// With String
serialize("Hello World!", out);

// With int
serialize(2547, out);

// with byte-array
serialize(new byte[]{1,3,5,6}, out);

// with userdefined object
serialize(new MyObject(), out);
```

Comment: You could add that in case OP wants to do same with primitive like `int` or `double`, he had to first convert them to the corresponding object `Integer` or `Double`

Comment: @vincrichaud good point, but whenever he's calling this method, autoboxing will already do that for him.

Answer (score -1):

> is it possible to reuse the same method for primitive [types]

Yes.

> and reference object types

You are already doing so.

> and what should I change in the method?

Nothing. Just call it with whatever you like. Autoboxing will take care of it for you.

Why you are declaring `throws FileNotFoundException` from a method that cannot throw it is another mystery.